# Postfix Failed Delivery Problem

Tags: linux, postfix, email

I'm getting this message for one of the mail accounts on my system:

> Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; cannot append message to file /username: cannot
>   create file exclusively: Permission denied

I earlier deleted /var/spool/mail/username.lock for this user and may also have temporarily moved /var/spool/mail/username. The permissions for /var/spool/mail/username are:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 username mail 0 May  6 00:08 /var/spool/mail/username
```

I don't know why this mail account is getting messages returned. What could be causing this error message?

Comment: What is your delivery software configured in Postfix (local_transport= or virtual_transport)? Please also post the master.cf where the delivery software is configured.

Comment: Could be a selinux problem. Check audit.log for alerts from postfix.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two problems.  You probably need 660 on that mail spool, you probably also don't have write permissions for the postfix user on /var/spool/mail.